# not able to log to mongodb 3.0 using log4mongo-java-0.7.4 jar

Tags: java, mongodb, logging

As part of the project, log4mongo-java-0.7.4 is used to log to mongodb 2.x which is working fine. Now we have to support MongoDB 3.x. But using log4mongo-java-0.7.4 jar with having mongo-java-driver-3.2.1.jar dependency, logging to MongoDB 3.x is not supported.

Can anyone please help me in fixing this problem with log4mongo-java jar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the code for a while, I was able to fix this issue. Since the authentication mechansim for Mongo 3.x is different than the way it does in 2.x, you have to modify the getMongo() method from MongoDbAppender.java the way it returns Mongo object as below.

```
protected Mongo getMongo(String hostname, String port, String userName, String password, String databaseName)
throws UnknownHostException
{
     String authMech = "SCRAM-SHA-1";
     if ((this.version != null) && (this.version.contains("2."))) {
         authMech = "MONGODB-CR";
     }
     MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + userName + ":" + password + "@" + hostname + ":" + port + "/?authSource=" + databaseName + "&authMechanism=" + authMech);
     MongoURI mongoUri = new MongoURI(uri);
     return new Mongo(mongoUri);
}
```

Comment: I think `this.version.contains("2.")` should change to start with.